# React Native Facebook Login and Branch AppDelegate

Tags: facebook, react-native, branch.io

I am trying to set up facebook login and branch deep linking for my react native app. Individually I can get them to work fine but I am not able to get them to work together in iOS.

I think the problem is with AppDelegate.m

Facebook Login (react-native-facebook-login) requires:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // ...
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  // return YES;
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

Branch (react-native-branch-deep-linking) requires:

```
// Initialize the Branch Session at the top of existing application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  // Uncomment this line to use the test key instead of the live one.
  // RNBranch.useTestInstance()
  RNBranch.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, isReferrable: true) // <-- add this

  //...
}

// Add the openURL and continueUserActivity functions
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  return RNBranch.branch.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
  return RNBranch.continue(userActivity)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
     return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation] ||
     RNBranch.branch.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```